# Use split for specific elements of multidimensional list

Tags: python, list, split, nested-lists

I have the following list (the actual file is much larger and complex)

```
a = [[['3x5'], ['ff']], [['4x10'], ['gg']]]
```

I would like to use the split functionality for the first element in the list and get the value in which appears after "x". The final results should be 5 and 10 in this case. I tried to use split in this format

```
for line in a:
    print str(line[0]).split("x")[1]
```

but the output is

```
5']
10']
```

I know I can easily manipulate the output to get 5 and 10 but what is the correct way of using split in this case?

And I am interested in using split for specific element of a list (first elements in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't the list to a string object, however, you can do it use:

```
>>> [i[0][0].split('x')[1] for i in a]
['5', '10']
```

I think you also want to convert the output to int object, then you can simply add an `int()` like below:

```
>>> [int(i[0][0].split('x')[1]) for i in a]
[5, 10]
```

---

However, if you don't need save the output into a list, but print it out instead, you can just use the same code, but write another version:

```
a = [[['3x5'], ['ff']], [['4x10'], ['gg']]]                                     
for i in a:                                          
    print(i[0][0].split('x')[1])
```

Output:

```
5
10
```

---

Remember that my code will failed (raise `IndexError: list index out of range`) when `a` is... For example `[[['3x5'], ['ff']], [['kk'], ['gg']]]` (the first element in one of the sublists isn't in format like `'3x5'`).

However, a simple `if` can fix this:

```
>>> a = [[['3x5'], ['ff']], [['kk'], ['gg']]]
>>> [int(i[0][0].split('x')[1]) for i in a]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 1, in <listcomp>
IndexError: list index out of range

>>> [int(i[0][0].split('x')[1]) for i in a if 'x' in i[0][0]]
[5]
```

Or even better, use RegEx to check, which can avoid something like `a = [[['3x5'], ['ff']], [['xxxxxxx'], ['gg']]]`:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = [[['3x5'], ['ff']], [['xxxxxxx'], ['gg']]]
>>> [int(i[0][0].split('x')[1]) for i in a if re.search(r'\d+x\d+', i[0][0])]
[5]
```

Another way, if you don't want `import re`:

```
>>> [int(i[0][0].split('x')[1]) for i in a 
...  if all(j.isdigit() for j in i[0][0].split('x'))]
[5]
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, your solution as well as Tim solution works for the sample I have written. But  the problem is I am only interested in the first element of the list. If for instance somewhere else there is "x" your solution will return that value as well. For example, if a = [[['3x5'], ['ff']], [['4x10'], ['5x12']]] the output will be 5 , 10 and 12 !

Comment: @Hamed requirements such as those should be explained in the question. Please edit it in now and remember it for next time.

Comment: @Hamed: Okay, I've already edited my answer. Now it also gives `5` and `10` when `a = [[['3x5'], ['ff']], [['4x10'], ['5x12']]]`, thanks for edit your question.

Comment: Thanks Tim and Kevin, I tried to edit my question so it will be clear for others.

Comment: Why not `[int(i[0][0].split('x')[1]) for i in a if 'x' in i[0][0]]`?

Comment: @BhargavRao: Because I want avoid something like `a = [[['3x5'], ['ff']], [['xxxxxxx'], ['gg']]]`.

Comment: Nice, Did you try your *own* answer with your *own* use case?

Comment: @BhargavRao: Yes, I did! *(yeah, kidding. Just edited)*.

Comment: Yep, when all fails, fall back to RegEx rite? You can do it using EAFP. But if you wanna use liscos and LBYL, you can use `[int(i[0][0].split('x')[1]) for i in a if i[0][0].split('x')[0].isdigit()]`.

Comment: @BhargavRao: Well, just added another way without RegEx before see your comment. I'm sure that my way is more *safe*.

Answer (score 3):

You need to dive one level deeper, and dont use str() on the list.

```
>>> a = [[['3x5'], ['ff']], [['4x10'], ['gg']]]
>>> for y in a:
...   if 'x' in y[0][0]:
...     print y[0][0].split('x')[-1]
5
10
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, that was a great help/

Comment: @Hamed you have 2 answers now to help with your issue. The 15 min mark has passed so you are free to accept whichever one you like if you feel your problem has been solved (you don't have to though). Also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers